# Order of a zero and Identity Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

In the book I am reading it states that:

> If $f$ is holomorphic and not identical $0$ around $c$, then because of the Identity Theorem there exists a number $n$, such that:
> $f(c)=f'(c)=...=f^{(n-1)}(c)=0, f^{n}(c) \neq 0$
> We define:
> $o_c(f):=min${$n \in \mathbb{N}: f^{(n)}(c) \neq 0$}

Now I can't make the connection between the Identity Theorem and the above.

The book is using

Identity Theorem:

Let $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a non empty, connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. For $f,g: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ the following are equivalent:

i) $f \equiv g$

ii) The set ${w \in G : f(w)=g(w)}$ has a limit point (in $G$)

iii) There exists a point $c \in G$, such that $f^{(n)}(c)=g^{(n)}(c)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Could someone explain to me how to get to the conclusion stated at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further context, the number $n$ here can be zero (by that I mean, $f(c)\neq0$ is possible). The point is, if the statement *didn’t* hold, then $f^{(n)}(c)\equiv0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N_0$ and holomorphy and the identity theorem imply $f$ is identically equal to zero on every connected neighbourhood of $c$. Since the function $f$ is taken to be *not* identically zero, it is impossible for the statement to be false, that is, it is true: such $n$ must exist. **Here $g(z)=0$ is the function taken**.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Andres2003 You’re very welcome

Answer (score 1):

Take $g=0$.

The negation of $iii)$ is:  $\forall c ,\exists n$ such that $f^n(c)\ne0$.

Since there exists such an $n$ for all $c$ and $n$ is a natural number,  we can pass to the smallest such.